# Add mask to tabpanel on grid sort (extjs)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm working on an internal extjs 4 project. I have a viewport with tabpanel. Each tab has an associated grid with MANY records. When a user sorts, the column headings are still accessible and they can initiate a new sort while the first is still processing. I'd like to add a mask to either the tabpanel or full viewport while the sort is still in progress. Is there an easy solution to this? Sorry, I cannot post any code here as it's on our intranet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy. Run this code while your records are being sorted:

```
var loadmask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Sorting..."});
loadmask.show();
```

Note that `Ext.getBody()` could be substituted by another **element**, whatever you want, you should only keep in mind that Ext.LoadMask wraps **element**, so `getBody()`, `getEl()`, both work ...

Again, when your process is completed, simply use `loadmask.hide()`

Comment: Thanks!. My column in my grid are set to "sortable: true". How do I add the loadmask above?

Comment: I've not seen your code yet so I'm not quite sure. But simple remember that, whenever you want to place a loadmask onto a component, reference to it (for eg. through id) and use as above, with `Ext.getBody()` -> `yourComponent.getEl()`